# NSView controls not resizing?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, autosize

I have a NSView with a NSTableView inside of it.

If the view looks like this:

[image: Window before size]

And the size & position properties for the Scollview (and tableview) look like this:

[image: Inspector]

Then why when I resize the view, does it look like this:

[image: Window after size]

Are my autosizing properties not set correctly? To my understanding they should be?

Comment: The handles around the table view show you’re testing it in Interface Builder. How about testing it in Cocoa Simulator or your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clearer, you won’t see autoresizing behaviour whilst *designing* your view in Interface Builder unless the border of the subview coincides with the corresponding border of the superview and Live Autoresizing is enabled.

This behaviour exists because resizing the superview can be used to indicate that you want a certain margin between the subview area and the superview area — for instance, you might have a 100pt margin between the subview’s right border and the superview’s right border, and then increase that margin to, say, 200pt by dragging the superview handles.

**Edit:** On the other hand, if you want to resize the superview whilst keeping the margins according to the autoresizing mask, you can drag the superview handles whilst holding the alt/option key.

Use Cocoa Simulator (File -> Simulate Interface) in order to test your interface, including autoresizing behaviour.

Comment: If you want to resize the window or a view in it, using the autoresize mask on views inside, hold the command key while dragging.

Answer (score -1):

The table with its scroll view will autoresize to your view's size only if you enter dimensions in by hand in Size info panel. They will not autoresize if you drag view's handles with mouse.

Comment: Autoresizing is a function of the autoresizing mask. One can freely drag the handles to adjust the size of the subview (in this case, a table view) and this size will be taken into account during autoresize.